# Converting rows into headers(columns)

Tags: sql, excel, pivot, excel-2016

So I can do it both ways, 1. do it on SQL or 2. do it on excel.
I want to convert the data from the left to the configuration on the right.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcdJ6.png

**Pivoting it without aggregating the values.

Or how do I make SQL to return a data as such fashion? (standard SQL)
I was using 
"select device, date, time, values from table"
and the date&time on excel came from aggregation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a pivot table.

1. Select a cell within the source data.
2. In Ribbon: select Insert--> Pivot table--> Ok

In your pivot table options:

1. Put device in the columns fields,
2. Date&time in rows,
3. Values in values.

Select the table and copy/paste to a new sheet to obtain your table.